# How can a file created by dd be bigger than the partition?

Tags: partitioning, unix, dd

A teacher told that in my Unix course and I would like to know how a 10GB partition can handle a 1TB file ?

Comment: What is a "_To_"? Presumably you mean Terabyte / TB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your teacher is most likely referring to is something called "sparse files".   These are files which grow as they are written to, with the underlying disk holding the magic - thus, provided that the filesystem is empty (and specifically writing 0's is not empty) its possible to create a 10 gig sparse file/block device using only a fraction of that on disk.

Look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/170125/how-do-i-convert-a-linux-disk-image-into-a-sparse-file) superuser link for more details on sparse files - especially the first response which explains how to do it in DD.

Comment: oh okay that's what i was thinking it's like a having "1000 m² of void in 10m²" in some way ?

Comment: The filesystem doesn't record the zeroes, but rather records the `seek()` (which can skip forward or backward in a file)... It's sort of like holding an IOU for _n_ apples, rather than a bucket of _n_ apples.

Comment: Its a bit similar to those fake USB disks you get out of China which claim to be 128GIG, but are actually 4 gig - they just tell the OS they have more space then they do - but when you run out of actual space, bad things happen.  (Of-course, sparse files are designed to grow as needed, so you don't have problems until its more then the underlying disk, and they probably won't silently drop all your data)

Comment: lmao
fanks for the explaination